# Get a template error when I try to do this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net mvc 3 and I keep getting this error and I don't understand it since I am not using a template.

I have this in my partial view

```
@model ViewModels.FormViewModel

    <div="tabs-1">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Due.ToShortDateString())
    </div>
```

in my viewmodel

```
public class FormViewModel
    {
        public DateTime Due { get; set; }


        public FormViewModel()
        {
            DueDate = DateTime.UtcNow;         
        }
    }
```

and I get this error

> Templates can be used only with field
>   access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or
>   single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Templates can be used only with field
>   access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or
>   single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Due)
```

And if you want some format for this date:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Due { get; set; }
```

and then:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Due)
```

of if you really want to use this `.ToShortDateString()` method you need to use a non-strongly typed helper (obviously that's something I would recommend against):

```
@Html.TextBox("Due", Model.Due.ToShortDateString())
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Ok I think I used a bad example on there as ya it gets rendered to a string anyways. Say if I want to use "ToShortDateString()" why can I not use it?

Comment: @chobo2, you could specify formats using the `DisplayFormat` attribute and `Html.EditorFor` helper.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - so what I am using is considered a template? So any of the for helpers are templates and to alter them I either have to edit them like Tomas Lycken said or to use data annotations to do the look?

Comment: @chobo2, `EditorFor` is for templates which you could override and it will use any attributes on your model property such as DisplayFormat. `TextBoxFor` will always generate a textbox input. Both take a lambda expression. This lambda expression should only return a property on your model. You cannot call any methods. The final option (one which existed since ASP.NET MVC 1) is to use non-strongly typed helper where you hardcode the name and the value.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov  - Well maybe I will look into these template ones. there is not too much of a difference if I just have partial view with EditFor in it verus having a partial view in a template folder? I was reading about "DisplayName" and I still don't get it and it's use.

Comment: @chobo2, there is a difference between editor templates (`Html.EditorFor`) and display templates (`Html.DisplayFor`). Editor templates (located in the `EditorTemplates` subfolder) allow you to provide a partial for editing the model property you used in the lambda expression whereas display templates (located in the `DisplayTemplates` subfolder) should be used for only displaying values (no forms, no input fields). This being said there is only a semantical difference. You could perfectly fine put input fields into a display template and it's gonna work, it's just that it is not right.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov  - I was talking about what the difference between making a a custom template or just having a partial view with either edit/display fields.

Comment: @chobo2, the difference is that templates handle automatically the naming of the input fields in complex object hierarchies. They also work with collection properties so that you don't have to write loops in your views. Templates are automatically applied for each element of the collection making your view code very concise.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov  - if you want to generate a dropdown list which one do you use?

Comment: @chobo2, I would use `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ItemId, Model.Items)`. This code generates a `<select>` form field so it would probably be situated in the editor template of some more complex object of my view model which I would have rendered in my main view like this `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeComplexProperty)`. Of course the editor template could contain some other stuff. This way if tomorrow I decide to use something else than a `<select>` field for editing this complex property all I have to do would be to change my editor template and all view using it will automatically be updated.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - you would make a custom template and you would call it up by @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeComplexProperty)? this or what is SomeComplexProperty being stored and called from?

Comment: @chobo2, `SomeComplexProperty` is a property of the view model passed to the view from the controller. It might contain some other simple properties for which I would generate corresponding input fields in the editor template by using `@Html.TextBoxFor`, `@Html.TextAreaFor`, `@Html.CheckBoxFor`, `@Html.DropDownListFor`, ...

Comment: When you write `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeComplexProperty)`, ASP.NET MVC will look for a file called `ComplexPropType.cshtml` in the `EditorTemplates` subfolder where `ComplexPropType`is the type of `SomeComplexProperty`.

Comment: as so this file would just contain the dropdown list in it. sort of like if I were to override the date I would make a file.

Answer (score 7):

There is an overload that can help achieve this, while keeping it strongly typed.

```
// Specify that you're providing the format argument (string)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Due, format: Model.Due.ToShortDateString())

// Or use the overload with format and html options, where null is the htmloptions
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Due, Model.Due.ToShortDateString(), null)
```

Answer (score 5):

You're getting the error because the `.TextBoxFor()` html helper is using a built-in template (a textbox for string input), and you're giving it a lambda expression that is too complicated (i.e. does not belong to the set of types listed in the message).

To solve the problem, either change the type of the property you want to edit to a `string`, so MVC can use the default string template, or let MVC use the default datetime template instead. I'd recommend the latter:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Due)
```

If you're not happy with the way your users are asked to edit a date, put a partial view named "DateTime.cshtml" in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates where you build the editor so it works the way you want.

Comment: @ Tomas Lycken -Is this new I never remember it having problems before I started to use razor? If I built my own then all dates would get this? Even ones I would not want to? Like for instance if I wanted only one of the dates to have a ToShortDateString() but all the others to have just render like a default could this be done?

Comment: @ Tomas Lycken - so what I did was too complicated? does it not convert it to a string first then put's it in the textbox? Where can I read more about this(about what these for textbox can handle) it just seems so weird

Comment: @chobo2: The problem is not that it is a very complicated thing to *render* - it's just that the hook-up to the name of the ViewModel property (that will be used for the `name` attribute of the input field) becomes much more complicated once you allow deeper statements than the ones listed in your error message. If you want to affect the output of your dates, use the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute (or one of the other attributes available), or create your own template.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using *MVC* and have an inline code element, try setting a parameter like this -

```
@{
string parameterValue = DateTime.Parse(@item.Value).ToShortDateString();

}

@Html.DisplayFor(model => parameterValue)
```

Comment: I didn't need the DateTime.Parse just simply string datevalue = item.LastUpdate.ToShortDateString();

Answer (score 0):

You are misleading the application by passing a method in the parameter of `textboxfor` instead of passing an expression.

You had :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Due.ToShortDateString())
```

Store your result in a variable and then use an expression. Try this

```
var shortDate = Model.Due.ToShortDateString();
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => shortDate )
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding format in model Use @Value Annotations as below

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Due new {@Value=Model.Due.ToShortDateString()})