# TextBoxFor for Nullable type

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, html.textboxfor, htmlextensions

How can i user `TextBoxFor`  for nullable type, in my case `DateTime?`

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaseDate.Value.ToShortDateString(), new { @class = "def-text-input datetime-input" })%>
```

I try this, but get error :

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be
>   used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array
>   index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a template error when I try to do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892248/get-a-template-error-when-i-try-to-do-this)

Comment: What type of page is this?  If it's a Create page, you could simply use jQuery UI's datepicker alongside the input which will automatically format the date into a short date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Html.EditorFor

```
<%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.LeaseDate, "Date")%>
```

Note the parameter "Date". This is a reference to an EditorTemplate (a usercontrol usualy located in the "Views/Shared/EditorTemplate" folder). If not present create the usercontrol/file your self "Date.ascx"

Now the EditorFor method will use this control as a template. A single place to control all your Date fields that use this template!

Example of the UserControl "Date.ascx"

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%
    ViewDataDictionary attributes = ViewData;
    attributes.Add("class", "def-text-input datetime-input");
%>
<%= Html.TextBox(string.Empty, string.Format("{0:d-M-yyyy}", Model), attributes) %>
```

Comment: i suposse  there is even simplier solution

Answer (score 0):

As the other guys mentioned you could do formatting on the model

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime LeaseDate { get; set; }
```

and then call

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LeaseDate)
```

on your view

But on the other hand, if you want to stick with formatting on view, you can use

```
@Html.TextBox("LeaseDate", Model.LeaseDate.ToShortDateString())
```

Happy coding

Answer (score -1):

`TextBoxFor` should be used for a property on your ViewModel:

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaseDate, new { @class = "def-text-input datetime-input" })%>
```

If you want to format your date, you can use the `DataFormatString` property on the `DisplayFormat` attribute on your ViewModel:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime LeaseDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: don't know why, but it's doesn't help.

Comment: How about if you are using `Html.EditorFor` instead of `Html.TextBoxFor`?

Comment: i want to skip this solution

Answer (score -2):

model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode= true]
DateTime? dateAssign { get; set; }
```

view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myObject.dateAssign)
```

Comment: don't know why, but it's doesn't help